# Probability of multiple chances with at least one result

Tags: probability

There are some similar questions but I can't solve this to my reality.

In a lottery, say that are 10000 balls, and only 36 are the ones that I want.
Ok so for 1 ball randomly selected, I will get a 36/10000 or 0.36%.

And what if I want that at least one ball is one of the 36ish ones for 5000 randomly balls selected, considering for every try the ball got is put back?

And what if for the 5000 tries I want that the 36 balls appear n times?

Comment: $36/10000=0.36\%$

Comment: Are you drawing with replacement or without replacement?

Answer (score 0):

```
And what if I want that at least one ball is one of the 36ish ones for 5000 
randomly balls selected, considering for every try the ball got is put back?
```

**Hint**: Think of the binomial distribution.

```
And what if for the 5000 tries I want that the 36 balls appear n times?
```

You mean, that n times one of the 36 balls appears ? If so, then the binomial distribution will be helpful, too.

Comment: @DarkHyudrA What have you calculated ? And which situation is it now ? Mention all the relevant informations